# Update rows returned by a complex SQL query with data from query result

Tags: postgresql, join, sql-update

I have a multi-table join and want to update a table based on the result of that join. The join table produces both the scope of the update (only those rows whose effort.id appears in the result should be updated) and the data for the update (a new column should be set to the value of a calculated column).

I've made progress but can't quite make it work. Here's my statement:

```
UPDATE 
    efforts
SET 
    dropped_int = jt.split
FROM 
(
SELECT 
    ef.id, 
    s.id split, 
    s.kind, 
    s.distance_from_start, 
    s.sub_order, 
    max(s.distance_from_start + s.sub_order) 
        OVER (PARTITION BY ef.id) AS max_dist
FROM 
    split_times st
LEFT JOIN splits s ON s.id = st.split_id
LEFT JOIN efforts ef ON ef.id = st.effort_id
) jt
WHERE 
    ((jt.distance_from_start + jt.sub_order) = max_dist) 
    AND 
    kind <> 1;
```

The SELECT produces the correct join table:

```
id  split kind dfs     sub max_dist dropped dropped_int
403  33     2  152404   1   152405  TRUE    33
404  33     2  152404   1   152405  TRUE    33
405  31     2  143392   1   143393  TRUE    33
406  31     2  143392   1   143393  TRUE    33
407  29     2  132127   1   132128  TRUE    33
408  29     2  132127   1   132128  TRUE    33
409  29     2  132127   1   132128  TRUE    33
```

and does indeed update the efforts.id column, but there are two problems: First, it updates all efforts, not just those that are produced from the query, and second, it sets effort.id to the split value of the first row in the query result, but I need it to set each effort to the associated split value.

If this were non-SQL, it might look something like:

```
jt_rows.each do |jt_row|
  efforts[jt_row].dropped_int = jt[jt_row].split
end
```

But I don't know how to do that in SQL. It seems like this should be a fairly common problem, but after a couple of hours of searching I'm coming up short.

How should I modify my statement to produce the described result? If it matters, this is Postgres 9.5. Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

EDIT:

I did not get a workable answer but ended up solving this with a mixture of SQL and native code (Ruby/Rails):

```
dropped_splits = SplitTime.joins(:split).joins(:effort)
   .select('DISTINCT ON (efforts.id) split_times.effort_id, split_times.split_id')
   .where(efforts: {dropped: true})
   .order('efforts.id, splits.distance_from_start DESC, splits.sub_order DESC')
update_hash = Hash[dropped_splits.map { |x| [x.effort_id, {dropped_split_id: x.split_id, updated_at: Time.now}] }]
Effort.update(update_hash.keys, update_hash.values)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a condition in the WHERE clause that relates `efforts` table with a subquery:
  `efforts.id = jt.id`
that is:

```
WHERE 
    ((jt.distance_from_start + jt.sub_order) = max_dist) 
    AND 
    kind <> 1
    AND
    efforts.id = jt.id
```

Comment: This does not work. I ended up solving the problem with a combination of SQL and Rails. See my update for details.